Azure Network Function Manager
Is there a REST API support for Azure Network Function Manager, especially for deploying individual network functions to your on-premises environment?
I find unsupported API's but not the supported REST API.

Oh again I found the answer in official Azure document itself. Azure Hybrid Network REST API also support Azure Network Function Manager for deploying individual network functions to your on-premises environment.
Source of the information:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/hybridnetwork/
